# Transparency Effects in KDE Plasma, not supported by color scheme

Tags: kubuntu, 17.04, plasma

Using Kubuntu 17.04 with Plasma 5.9.4

I installed a few Themes like Maia and Breath, which usually can use Transparency Effects, for the Console Background, Application Dashboard and the Panel. 
The Desktop Effect for Translucency is already activated. And I tried to set the opacity, but it does not seem to work.

Always when I try to set the Theme in Konsole, I get the Message:

> This color scheme uses a transparent background which does not appear
>   to be supported on your desktop

Is there a package I need to install, for this? Or do I miss something else? For any Idea, I would be grateful.

[image: Screenshot for Konsole, and the Dock below is also set to 100% Transparency for the Background.]

Screenshot for Konsole, and the Dock below is also set to 100% Transparency for the Background.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: I added a Screenshot for Konsole. Cannot make some of the Application Dashboard, somehow.

Answer (score 25):

I had same issue but I got it solved when I changed rendering backend to XRender for my Nvidia card.

System Settings  --->  Display and Monitor  --->  Compositor.

Comment: Thank you! I changed my compositor from OpenGL 2.0 with OpenGL 3.1

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's the second time this saves me. I guess sometimes the updates rolls back the changes.

Comment: In my case the compositor wasn't starting automatically, thank you for the pointers!

Answer (score 3):

this can be solve by changing the option of compositor:

[image: Compositor option in Display and Monitor]

There were also several errors related to this same issue

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue recently with KDE Plasma.  When I went to 'System Settings -> Display and Monitor -> Compositor'.. there it stated that opengl detection was off, due to opengl causing KWin to crash in the past.

I switch back from opengl 3.1 to opengl 2.0, and re-enabled it... it is working (at least for now).

I think it is similar to this issue: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/kwin-crash-after-changing-rendering-backend-to-open-gl-3-1/30827

Answer (score 0):

I've had this message show up when I had a fullscreen game open (active but minimized/hidden) - not sure if it matters but the game used vulkan shaders. When I quit the game, the terminal window turned semi-transparent again.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It looks like you may be putting more information about your question into an answer. If you need to update your question, you can edit it at any time and let others provide answers.

Comment: @TommyPeanuts I'm not the person who asked the question, but thought I'd add a possible cause of their issue (that I had also experienced).

Comment: That's OK, but the same principle applies. If you have a solution, put it in the answers. If you have a comment, put it in the comments.